# How to fix dropdown within table getting cutoff by row container

Tags: html, css, angular

I have created an `ng-template` for a column in my table within angular. I have added a dropdown button within this cell template. However, because each row in the table is short in height the dropdown is being cut off by the row's container.

I'm trying to get the button to `overflow` out of the row.

I've tried adding some styling to the div setting the `overflow` to `visible` and it's not working. I've also tried changing the position to `absolute` on the dropdown. I think I may be styling it wrong somehow

```
<ng-template #soldOut let-row="row" let-value="value">
    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block"> 
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
        <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
          <button class="dropdown-item">Active</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item">Sold Out</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item">Manually Recheck</button>

        </div>
      </div>
</ng-template>
```

[image]

You can see the rest of the options are being cutoff.

Comment: can you share a fiddle or live link to check it! What is your CSS and what you try?

Comment: I don't really know how to set it up on fiddle since I'm using a template and have live data being pulled from an API

Comment: you said in your question you have a table, but I can't see any code of table, please add any more code that is related to this issue, I will try to fix and create a sample for you

Comment: From experience, creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is an important tool to understanding and debugging the issue--and of course it's a nice way to help the fine folks here who are trying to help you. :)

Comment: Can you please share the css code here, so that I can help you out from your problem.